# Is there a connection between uniform law of large number and Ibragimov's conjecture?

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

In limit theorems, one of the biggest problem is to give an answer to Ibragimov's conjecture, which states the following:

> Let $(X_n,n\in\Bbb N)$ be a strictly stationary $\phi$-mixing sequence, for which $\mathbb E(X_0^2)<\infty$ and $\operatorname{Var}(S_n)\to +\infty$. Then $S_n/\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}S_n}$ (where    $S_n:=\sum_{j=1}^nX_j$) is asymptotically normally distributed.

$\phi$-mixing coefficients are defined as 
$$\phi_X(n):=\sup(|\mu(B\mid A)-\mu(B)|, A\in\mathcal F^m, B\in \mathcal F_{m+n},m\in\Bbb N ),$$
where $\mathcal F^m$ and $\mathcal F_{m+n}$ are the $\sigma$-algebras generated by the $X_j$, $j\leqslant m$ (respectively $j\geqslant m+n)$, and $\phi$-mixing means that $\phi_X(n)\to 0$.

My question here :Is there a connection between [uniform law of large number](https://www.google.dz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQygQwAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLaw_of_large_numbers%23Uniform_law_of_large_numbers&ei=MxyPVd2oDsasUcLMgeAB&usg=AFQjCNHz0wqjKRJbzi5IwR3IiirvQtE8Lw&sig2=8pYG5gmgCEFJ6THUnoVPQg) and Ibragimov's conjecture ?
Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{S_n}{Var(S_n)}$ is asymptotically normal?

Comment: yeah , I would like so to know if it is asymptotically normal ,and i woul like also to know in the general if there is a clear connection between 2

Comment: You can take a look here as a starting point: http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/8112/notes/stationary.pdf

Comment: @d.k.o.,thank you for the paper

Comment: Before trying to establish a link between Ibragimov's conjecture and uniform law of large numbers, a first step could be to look for a link between the central limit theorem and the uniform law of large numbers.